# My event handler keeps reporting an error on my overloaded methods

Tags: java

I'm using Java, and I'm trying to call an overloaded method in an event handler. `calculateCost()` and `calculateCost(int,boolean)` are the methods I'm overloading, now.
This is the `calculateCost(int,boolean)` along with the `calculateCost()` method below:

```
public double calculateCost() { //calculates cost of computer &peripherals.
    if (printerCB.isSelected()) {
        return baseComputer() + printer();
    }
    if (dellMouseCB.isSelected()) {
        return baseComputer() + dellMouse();
    }
    if (logiKeyboardCB.isSelected()) {
        return baseComputer() + logiKeyboard();
    }
    if (canonScannerCB.isSelected()) {
        return baseComputer() + canonScanner();
    }
    if (razerMouseCB.isSelected()) {
        return baseComputer() + razerMouse();
    }
    if (razerKeyboardCB.isSelected()) {
        return baseComputer() + razerKeyboard();
    }
    return baseComputer();
}

public double claculateCost(int quant, boolean shipp) { //calculates the shipping rate for the computer, &peripherals.
    quant = 1;
    double total = calculateCost();
    if (groundShipRB.isSelected() || airShipRB.isSelected() || fedExRB.isSelected()) {
        shipp = true;
        if (shipp == true) {
            {
                if (groundShipRB.isSelected()) {
                    while (quant >= 100) {
                        return calculateCost() * 0.05;
                    }
                }
                if (airShipRB.isSelected()) {
                    return calculateCost() * 0.10;
                }
                if (fedExRB.isSelected()) {
                    return calculateCost() * 0.20;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the Code inside the event handler:

```
private void costCalcWShipButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int quant = 1;
    double dsqnt = 0.00;
    double cost = calculateCost();
    boolean shipp = false;
    double rate = calculateCost(quant, shipp);
    outputTextPane.setText("");
    outputTextPane.setText(outputTextPane.getText() + "Quantity." + "\t\t" + "Price." + "\t\t" + "Shipping rate" + "\t\t" + "Quantity discount(per $100)." + "\n");
    outputTextPane.setText(outputTextPane.getText() + quant + "\t\t" + cost * quant + "\t\t" + rate + "\t\t" + discountPercentage(quant, dsqnt) + "\n");
    for (quant = 100; quant <= 1000; quant = quant + 100) {
        outputTextPane.setText(outputTextPane.getText() + quant + "\t\t" + cost * quant + "\t\t" + rate + "\t\t" + discountPercentage(quant, dsqnt) + "\n");
    }
}
```

The `calculateCost()` method works when I put it into the event handler for the GUI, but when I try calling the `calculateCost(int,boolean)` it gives me this error:

```
error: method calculateCost in class compCostCalc cannot be applied to given types;
int quant=1;double dsqnt=0.00;double cost=calculateCost();boolean shipp=false;double rate=calculateCost(quant,shipp);
required: no arguments
found: int,boolean
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error.
```

This has confused me for a while, any feedback I can get to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your code: `claculateCost` instead of `calculateCost` (in the method definition).

Comment: Thanks, Is it common for people to overlook typos?

Comment: @pati3ntzero No, if you are using IDE.